# Running a script at the begin of the shutdown protocol (not at the end)?

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

Is it possible to run a script *before* the shutdown? That means at a point where the system is still fully functional.

I tried to put my shutdown script in `/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/test-script`. It will be executed but from my understanding it is only executed immediately before the shutdown takes place. For instance, the disk is already mounted in read-only mode. This can be fixed, but wrapping the script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
mount -oremount,rw /
... do something ...
mount -oremount,ro /
```

What I require and cannot get to work, though, is internet connection. When the script is executed, the internet connection seems to be no longer available.

**Is it possible to run a script right at the begin of the shutdown protocol?**

I'm testing with Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/39226/29509.

To sum it up, this solution works for me (on Ubuntu 16.04):

Create a file `/etc/systemd/system/my-cleanup.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test cleanup at shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/path/to/my-cleanup-script.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

(Assuming the shutdown script is available under `/path/to/my-cleanup-script.sh` and is executable.)

Finally, enable the systemd service via:

```
sudo systemctl enable my-cleanup.service
sudo systemctl start my-cleanup.service
```

Answer (score 0):

With respect to Answer 1. I trust the solution will work "during" shutdown but as  the OP asked `it will run right at the begin of the shutdown`, I am not sure.
This link is more explicit about the moment a script will be executed during shutdown: http://ccm.net/faq/3348-execute-a-script-at-startup-and-shutdown-on-ubuntu
Please note I did not test it in my system, I'm just relaying my findings.